# Unable to get responsive right-align for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Why doesn't my bootstrap code scale down to mobile?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Checkout
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

On my computer I have to physically scroll to the right.

See the code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/nVw2V/

**How can I get this to right-align down to mobile?**

Thanks for all info

FYI: I tested by resizing the browser window and running [via PhoneGap] in an Android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `bootstrap-responsive.css` stylesheet in tandem with the bootstrap stylesheet in order to cover mobile devices.

Just include the following "after" the bootstrap.css stylesheet declaration:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nVw2V/1/

Comment: Thanks, that mostly fixed it [**+1**], however it is still a [little cut out](http://i48.tinypic.com/az3ix.jpg)... I could add some `border-right` but that feels kind of messy. How is this meant to be solved?

Comment: @AT can't see your screenshot for some reason, can you upload it to imgur.com?

Comment: @AT found the problem, the `.navbar-fixed-bottom` class has a `margin:0 -20px` property added to it that cuts off a piece of the content on both sides. If you remove that behavior it works fine, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nVw2V/2/

Comment: @AT the fix was `.navbar-fixed-bottom { margin:0; }` by the way.